# Bayesian belief network calculations

Tags: algorithm, bayesian-networks

I am using MSBNX (microsoft's bbn software) and I cannot figure out how it makes its calculations. This is what my network looks like. [image]

The probabilities for rain are: Yes-> 0.2 , no -> 0.8 JakesLawn wet and rain -> 0.9, not wet and rain -> 0.1, no rain and wet -> 0.2, no rain and not wet -> 0.8. TracyLawn rain and wet -> 0.9, rain and not wet -> 0.1, no rain and wet -> 0.2, no rain and not wet -> 0.8. Now if i set tracylawn to observed wet I get this: [image] How is the the chance that it rained, 0.5294, calculated here?

Comment: Are you familiar with Baye's Law?

Comment: So is P(B|A) = 0.9, and P(A) = 0.2? Whats P(B)

Comment: P(B) would be the overall probability of trace watering her lawn, across all cases.